# How to CSRF secure a form that posts to another page?

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, csrf

I have a little issue concerning CSRF security and a login form. The form works as follows:

In the main layout a view helper creates a login form and will later also display a user specific menu when a user has been authenticated.

```
    // User menu viewhelper
public function authentication()
{
    // Check if user is authenticated or not
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

    if(!$auth->hasIdentity())
    {
        $form = new Application_Form_Login();
        $form->setAction($this->_view->url(array('action' => 'login'), 'ucp', true));

        return $form;
    }
    else
    {
        // return user specific menu
    }
}
```

The form posts to a UcpController containing all the user control panel logic, such as logging in/out and displaying user specific information.

```
    // loginAction in UcpController
public function loginAction()
{
    if(Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity())
    {
        $this->_redirect('/');
        return;
    }

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $form = new Application_Form_Login();

    if($request->isPost())
    {
        if($form->isValid($post = $request->getPost()))
        {
            // Do authentication stuff here.
        }
    }

    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

Sadly this way the CSRF token fails to match and I'm clueless how to solve this problem. Am I missing something here? Should I remove the CSRF validation all together?

```
// The CSRF protection element as added to the login form
$this->addElement('hash', 'csrf',
    array(
        'ignore' => true
    )
);
```

Thanks in advance, your help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! I ran into someone who encountered the same problem. The cause is very strange: http://tinyurl.com/3fkg8bk (ZF Forums).

As it turned with me, my favicon was returning an HTTP 500 code as the file was non-existent. This apparently triggers a new CSRF to be generated. I don't have the slightest clue why, but it solved my problem to create an icon and upload it to the webroot.

Thanks for thinking along with me at least!

Comment: Great now I ran into a problem when I post the small form and the credentials aren't correct, the large form loads which causes 2 identical forms to load on the page. The token fails to validate again when I submit the large form.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct, I think the problem could be somewhere else. To debug this issue do this:

Using firebug inspect the generated `Application_Form_Login`, especially the CSRF token, then when you post the data try to `Zend_Debug::dump` the `$_SESSION` and the `$_POST` array in your loginAction and compare the result. You should find a match between your posted data and your session data.

You should search for a match between the sent post variable and a session variable named `Zend_Form_Element_Hash_salt_<name-of-your-element>`, if the values match then the error is elsewhere and you should dump `$form->getMessages()` to find it.

As zerkms pointed out in a comment, my previous sentence is wrong. I looked at the [implementation](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Form/Element/Hash.php) and I saw that the CSRF token in ZF change once in 300 seconds, with this timeout a token expiration should not be the problem in your case.

Comment: New CSRF token per request is really painful. Token-per-session is enough and as secured as per-http-request implementation.

Comment: @zerkms I was wrong, in ZF the token changes once in 300 seconds (by default) I've just updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: This is rather curious, the session data shows an empty array.

Comment: I've also identified that the token of the "small" login form from the view helper differs than the form object that is being validated with.